# Zend_Form array of inputs

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, zend-form, ini

Using Zend_Form, how would I create form elements like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" value="" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" value="" />
```

If i don't know how many files user want to upload.
Now the settings for the input type="file" look

```
form.elements.file.type = "File"
form.elements.file.options.required = true
form.elements.file.options.label = "File"
form.elements.file.options.validators.extension.validator = "Extension"
form.elements.file.options.validators.extension.options.extension = "gif,jpg,jpeg,png,swf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this

```
    $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File("image");
    $image->setAttrib('multiple', true)
           ->setIsArray(true)
           ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'gif,jpg,jpeg,png,swf');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. .ini config looks like  
`form.elements.file.type = "File"`  
`form.elements.file.options.multiple = true`  `form.elements.file.options.isarray = true`  
`form.elements.file.options.required = true`  
`form.elements.file.options.label = "File"`  
`form.elements.file.options.validators.extension.validator = "Extension"  
    form.elements.file.options.validators.extension.options.extension = "gif,jpg,jpeg,png,swf"`